# Update Combobox on Save and Delete

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a bound combo box with employee profile names. I have two buttons:  save and delete buttons.

When I edit a selected profile, I hit save and automatically the change is reflected in the bound combo box, but when I hit delete or create new profile, I have to close the app and when I open it I see the changes in the bound combo box.

The combobox.Refresh() no work

This is my code:

```
Private Sub deleteselectedprofile_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_deleteprofile_oninsideprofiledittap1.Click
    Dim mconn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=epmapp_db;Integrated Security=true;")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    cmd.Connection = mconn
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = "delete GeneralInfo where RecordId= " + cbox_profiles.SelectedValue.ToString

    Try
        If MessageBox.Show("¿Está seguro de querer borrar este perfil?", _
        "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, _
        MessageBoxIcon.Warning) = DialogResult.No Then
            mconn.Close()
            MsgBox("Operación Cancelada")
        Else
            mconn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Su perfil se ha actualizado exitosamete")
            Clear_Form_tap1()
            disabling_controlstap1()
            btn_newprofile_onload_tap1.Visible = True
            btn_saveprofile_oninside_profileedit_tap1.Visible = False
            btn_editprofile_oncboxselectiontap1.Visible = False
            btn_cancelprofileedit_onprofileselectiontap1.Visible = False
            btn_deleteprofile_oninsideprofiledittap1.Visible = False
            cbox_profiles.Enabled = True
            ErrorProvider1.Clear()

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        mconn.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

I set my combo box in the Design Tab using the...

```
Combo Box Task
Use Data Bound Items
Data Binding Mode
Data Source = GeneralInfoBindingDource
Display  Member = Nombre
Value Member = RecordId
Selected Value = none
```

My save button code...

```
Private Sub btn_saveprofile_oninside_profileedit_tap1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_saveprofile_oninside_profileedit_tap1.Click

    Me.Validate()
    Me.GeneralInfoBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.GeneralInfoTableAdapter.Update(Me.Epmapp_dbDataSet)
    Try
        MessageBox.Show("Su perfil ha actualizado exitosamete")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Clear_Form_tap1()
    disabling_controlstap1()
    btn_saveprofile_oninside_profileedit_tap1.Visible = False
    btn_cancelprofileedit_onprofileselectiontap1.Visible = False
    btn_deleteprofile_oninsideprofiledittap1.Visible = False
    btn_editprofile_oncboxselectiontap1.Visible = False
    btn_newprofile_onload_tap1.Visible = True
    cbox_profiles.Enabled = True
    ErrorProvider1.Clear()

End Sub
```

I have try a few codes but none works for me. Can any one help me with a code for this small issue?

Comment: you should mention what programming language is used

Answer (score 1):

If I followed this correctly, when you delete a record you are doing so directly in the database.  However, you are not updating your datasource (GeneralInfoBindingDource).   My guess is you have the same issue when you create a new item.  The database is updated, so when it reloads the data from the database its correct. (When you reopen it).

You need to update your datasource.

Your save works because you are updating the datasource, rather than writing changes to the database without updating it.

```
Me.GeneralInfoBindingSource.EndEdit()
Me.GeneralInfoTableAdapter.Update(Me.Epmapp_dbDataSet)
```